# Meteor page reload extremely slow?

Tags: meteor

I'm running Meteor in a VirtualBox Ubuntu machine and accessing it via my windows computer.

Refreshing the browser on my small meteor site takes 15 seconds. It's making 238 total requests which each take a bit of time and add up to my incredibly slow reload.

Are there any steps I can take to diagnose where the problem is? Shouldn't Meteor be bundling all these JS files and templates to make less requests?

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Turns out, the issue wasn't with Meteor at all. The bridged adapter on my Ubuntu Server VM was incredibly slow. Once I switched to a Virtio NAT adapter and set up my port forwards, my site went from ~16 second to ~2.5 second refreshes.

Answer (score 2):

Try launching Meteor in "production" mode (this will bundle all the files) in your VirtualBox.

```
meteor --production
```

Comment: Running it in product does reduce the requests down to 6, and it takes 1-1.5s to load. Still pretty slow, but obviously much improved. However, this doesn't really help with my problem, as I can't develop on it in production mode.

Comment: Are you subscribing to or loading into data context a really, really huge Collection?